# NSUserDefaults setObject not saving for first time

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsuserdefaults, nsdata, mac-app-store

My application saving NSData (contains bookmarked file reference) list to NSUserDefaults in somewhat following way, at any point of application process:

```
NSMutableArray *bookmarkedURLs = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[bookmarkedURLs addObject:bookmark]; // 'bookmark' is a NSData object 
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:bookmarkedURLs forKey:@"AppBookmarks"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

When application starts I checked through NSUserDefaults to populate saved NSData list:

```
bookmarkedURLs = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"AppBookmarks"] mutableCopy];
if (bookmarkedURLs.count == 0)
{
    bookmarkedURLs = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSLog(@"INITIALIZED");
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"STORES NSDATA LIST");
    ....
}
```

The problem I faced I can order in following steps:

1. There is no saved NSUserDefaults data by 'AppBookmarks' key
2. Save a NSData to NSUserDefaults by 'AppBookmarks' key
3. Restarts application
4. **Application tries to populate a NSMutableArray from NSUserDefaults' 'AppBookmarks' key but always found 0 records**
5. I save again a new NSData to 'AppBookmarks' key
6. Restarts application
7. Application tries to populate NSMutableArray from 'AppBookmarks' and this time it found saved record(s).
8. Any restart of application or new NSData addition to 'AppBookmarks' never fails thereafter

So whenever there is no saved data to NSUserDefaults and I saved a value, it's not loading or saving for first time. Any attempt to save and load is working after then.

Comment: Are you sure bookmark is NSURL Object?, as far as i know, NSUserDefault only works for arrays that contain NSData, NSString, NSNumber, NSDate, NSArray, or NSDictionary.

Comment: Thank you for pointing. I rectified my question.

Comment: try to change bookmarkedURLs = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"AppBookmarks"] mutableCopy];
with: bookmarkedURLs = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"AppBookmarks"]];

Comment: I don't think its the problem how we're loading - since the existing process works fine after *first* failed attempt. Save and load works good from 2nd time.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
NSMutableArray *bookmarkedURLs = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[bookmarkedURLs addObject:bookmark]; // 'bookmark' is a NSURL object 
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:bookmarkedURLs forKey:@"AppBookmarks"];
[defaults synchronize];
```

I hope this can help you.

Comment: Thank you; but storing NSUserDefaults to a field and using didn't helped either.

Comment: You asking how I generates `bookmark` object? It's a `NSURLBookmarkCreationWithSecurityScope` NSData object - so I creates it after a `NSOpenPanel` event when user choose any file/folder, I adds the selected file path to URL Bookmark and gets the NSData (`bookmark`) object.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like,

```
     NSUserDefaults *myDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

// for example
NSURL *url1;  // your url1
NSURL *url2;   // your url2

//Set data to userdefaults

NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:url1,url2, nil]; // Store urls directly in array

NSData *bookMarkdata = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:arr]; // convert whole array in data

[myDefaults setObject:bookMarkdata forKey:@"AppBookmarks"];  // save that data object to userdefaults
[myDefaults synchronize];

//Retreive data from userdefaults

NSData *resultData = [myDefaults objectForKey:@"AppBookmarks"];  //retrieve data from user defaults

NSMutableArray *resultArr = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:resultData]; // get result array from data
```

Comment: `[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:resultData]` always returns me null NSMutableArray, even by this `[[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:resultData] mutableCopy]`. I can confirm that at the time of calling `[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject: bookmarkedURLs]` I had more than 0 items in the mutable array.